# Executable Jar With Button setCellRenderer() not Working

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, tablecelleditor

I have a serious Problem.
I am Using Jtable in which i added a buttons using this code.

```
    TableColumn buttonColumn = tableSupplier.getColumnModel().getColumn(8);
    TableButton buttons = new TableButton();
    buttons.addHandler(new TableButton.TableButtonPressedHandler() {
        public void onButtonPress(int row, int column) {
            try {
                saveImageInFolder();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Utility.getFormFieldValidator().showErrorMessage();
            }
        }
    });

    buttonColumn.setCellRenderer(buttons);
    buttonColumn.setCellEditor(buttons);
```

My Button Class Code is like this.

```
package org.chillies.validator;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import org.chillies.view.SupplierList;

public class TableButton extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor,TableCellRenderer
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5647725208335645741L;

public interface TableButtonPressedHandler
    {
    /**
     * Called when the button is pressed.
     * @param row The row in which the button is in the table.
     * @param column The column the button is in in the table.
     */
    void onButtonPress(int row, int column);
}

private List<TableButtonPressedHandler> handlers;
private Hashtable<Integer, JButton> buttons;

public TableButton()
{
    handlers = new ArrayList<TableButtonPressedHandler>();
    buttons = new Hashtable<Integer, JButton>();
}

/**
 * Add a slide callback handler
 * @param handler
 */
public void addHandler(TableButtonPressedHandler handler)
{
    if (handlers != null)
    {
        handlers.add(handler);
    }
}

/**
 * Remove a slide callback handler
 * @param handler
 */
public void removeHandler(TableButtonPressedHandler handler)
{
    if (handlers != null)
    {
        handlers.remove(handler);
    }
}


/**
 * Removes the component at that row index
 * @param row The row index which was just removed
 */
public void removeRow(int row)
{
    if(buttons.containsKey(row))
    {
        buttons.remove(row);
    }
}

/**
 * Moves the component at oldRow index to newRow index
 * @param oldRow The old row index
 * @param newRow THe new row index
 */
public void moveRow(int oldRow, int newRow)
{
    if(buttons.containsKey(oldRow))
    {
        JButton button = buttons.remove(oldRow);
        buttons.put(newRow, button);
    }
}

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean selected, boolean focus, final int row, final int column)
{
    JButton button = null;
    if(buttons.containsKey(row))
    {
        button = buttons.get(row);
    }
    else
    {
        button = new JButton();
        if(value != null && value instanceof String)
        {
            button.setText((String)value);
        }
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if(handlers != null)
                {
                    for(TableButtonPressedHandler handler : handlers)
                    {
                        handler.onButtonPress(row, column);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        button.setBorder(null);
        button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(SupplierList.class
                .getResource("/org/chillies/resource/Add.png")).getImage()
                .getScaledInstance(20, 20, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));

        buttons.put(row, button);
    }

    return button;
}

public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean selected, int row, int column)
{
    JButton button = null;
    if(buttons.containsKey(row))
    {
        button = buttons.get(row);
    }
    else
    {
        button = new JButton();
        if(value != null && value instanceof String)
        {
            button.setText((String)value);
        }

        buttons.put(row, button);
    }

    return button;
}

public void setButtonText(int row, String text)
{
    JButton button = null;
    if(buttons.containsKey(row))
    {
        button = buttons.get(row);
        button.setText(text);
    }
}

public Object getCellEditorValue()
{
    return null;
}

public void dispose()
{
    if (handlers != null)
    {
        handlers.clear();
    }
}
}
```

But when I Export my Project into jar file it seem to have problem with this one line of code

```
 buttonColumn.setCellRenderer(buttons);
```

when i remove this line and run Jar file the project runs fine but when i add this line it doesn't even load the page .

Code works fine in eclipse.

And i am loading my view class static (just extra information).
Thanks for your time.

Comment: >> "it seem to have problem with this one line of code"  do you have a stack trace ?, what is the exact problem you are referring to ?

Comment: that is the problem bro there is no strack trace but where i remove this line it code works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i got the answer of my question i have modified some of the code of TableButton.java file   . after making some quick fixes i solved my issues.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you missed the main point of JTable design - a single renderer/editor to be used for entire table (for all rows I mean):

- you only have one instance of the renderer Component like JButton
- JTable calls getTableCellRendererComponent for each row
- you set the data on the renderer component (aka prepare for rendering it in a specific cell) in the getTableCellRendererComponent.

no Maps (Hashtables) needed.

the same applies to renderers and editors. if you want to know the row on which the button was pressed you just call jTable.getSelectedRow().

no custom TableButtonPressedHandler needed.